# What is the difference between getHost and getAuthority methods in URL class in Java?

Tags: java, networking

I have a series of strings (URLs) in different forms as:

1. `http://domain name.anything/anypath`
2. `https://dmain name.anything/anypath`
3. `http://www.domain name.anything/anypath`
4. `https://www.dmain name.anything/anypath`

These strings are saved in CSV file. I need to parse every URL in order to get the domain name only, `domain name.anything`. i.e, the part after the first `.` and before the first `/`.

I separated the strings using `split` method, then converted each string to a URL, then used the `toAuthority` function to get the domain name only. The problem is that, `toAuthority` and `toHost` are doing the same job for me, they include the `www.` that I don't want. Though, in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) from Oracle, it seems that `toAuthority` supposed to return the domain name without `www.`.

How can I extract the domain name part only without the `www.` of the URL ??

Comment: `getHost` gets the hostname and `getAuthority` gets the authority

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the difference between the getHost and getAuthority methods in the URL class?

To really understand this, you should read [URI specification - RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

The short answer is that the authority component consists of the host component together with an optional port number, username and password ... depending on the URL scheme that is used.

---

> How can I extract the domain name part only without the "www." of the URL ??

You call `getHost()`, test if it starts with the string `"www."` and if it does you remove it.

But before you start doing things like that, you need to understand that removing the "www." may give you a URL that doesn't work, or that resolves to a document or service that is different to the one the the original URL resolves to.  It is a bad idea to gratuitously tidy up URLs ... unless you have detailed knowledge of how the sites in question are organized.

The convention that "foo.com" and "www.foo.com" are the same place is *just* a convention, and a lot of sites don't implement it.  Removing "www." would be a bad idea because it is liable to turn resolvable URLs into URLs that don't resolve.

Comment: Adding the RFC specification and the foo.com/"www.foo.com" clarification was a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

you can use google guava to get the domain name from the host name:

```
InternetDomainName.from(hostname).topPrivateDomain().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to extract the effective second level domain. This is easy to extract for a small number of public suffixes such as .com, .net, .org by first getting the host name, as Stephen describes, and extracting the substring beginning with the second period from the end. Many public suffixes such as co.uk will break this simple algorithm though. A full list of public suffixes can be found here: http://publicsuffix.org/ You can then use the public suffixes in a look up table to get the effective second level domain.